# How to cite papers and books in R notebook [R]

Tags: r, r-markdown, citations, rnotebook

I would like to ask how to cite in R notebook like in the latex, for example when one get publication and get citation norm from google scholar: https://scholar.google.cz/scholar?hl=cs&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=wooldridge+introductory+econometrics&btnG=&oq=wool

How to cite this in Rmarkdown file?

```
---
title: "Spatial approaches for decision making proces of terrorists: The case of Europe"
author: Petr Hrobař
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
  chunk_output_type: console
---


{r set knitr options, echo = FALSE}
# set some knitr options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F,
                      message = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      fig.width=8, fig.height=5)



# Manski model
As mentioned by \cite{@book{wooldridge2016introductory,
  title={Introductory econometrics: A modern approach},
  author={Wooldridge, Jeffrey M},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Nelson Education}
}} the standard approach for any spatial econometrics modelling starts by not using spatial models at all.
```

I belived that using same approach as in latex `\cite` would work, however it is not. Is there some package that one need to install or is citation somehow integrated in default R notebook?

Comment: There's a guide here from RStudio. https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html. You save those citations in a bibtex file, link it in the yaml header, and cite with @wooldridge2016introductory.

Comment: Tagged [tag:r-markdown] and [tag:citations]

Answer (score 1):

## All in one:

I use this code to have citations stored **in** the `.Rmd` file itself:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    citation_package: natbib
biblio-style: apsr
references:
- id: baseR
  title: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing
  author:
  - family: R Core Team
    given: Team
  organization: R Foundation for Statistical Computing
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  year: 2019
  type: article
---

I cite R here: [@baseR]


Some content,
```

The code above will print the citation at the end of the html file when knited.

## External .bib file:

Alternatively I sometimes use an extern `.bib` file (e.g.if there are many citations):

Content of the `.Rmd` file:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
bibliography: ext/lit.bib
biblio-style: apsr
---

Cite here [@baseR] creates a parenthetical citation (R ..., 1900)
```

Content of `ext/lit.bib`:

```
@Manual{baseR,
    title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
    author = {{R Core Team}},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    year = {2019},
}
```